# Pages are in the wrong order when printing a booklet from InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, print-design, booklet

I am trying to print a 24 page booklet from InDesign and it keeps placing my pages in the below order:

- 24-1
- 23-2
- 22-3
- etc

Please let me know what I need to change with the attached image settings.

[image]

Comment: Do you understand print pagination? Please provide more information. How is the document set up? Reader spread, single pages?? Are those numbers correct or is it actually 24-1, 2-23, 22-3? (this order would be correct)

Comment: What are you actually trying to do and what order are you expecting? As already said the order you're getting (assuming you made a typo in the second spread) looks correct

Comment: Maybe you dont want a saddle stich booklet?

Comment: A "printer's spread" puts pages into proper order for printing. A "reader's spread" puts pages into proper order for reading. Searching those terms may also help you. Also, making a "dummy" is another search term for booklet preparation.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as @joojaa suggests, what you are seeing is a reordering of your pages designed for printing a booklet. This reordering is called imposition, which is the process where InDesign r-orders your pages so that they will print correctly if you are printing double-sided with two pages per spread. The only two pages that will appear in the "normal" order are the two pages that would be the center of your final brochure/booklet.

If you are fairly new to layout, and are making a brochure or booklet, it can be tempting to use the "booklet printing" option in InDesign.  But, unless you have designed specifically with this type of final product in mind, you will be very confused by the final output.

Just use the regular print command, and you should be fine.  If you do want to create something like a saddle-stitched booklet/brochure, then I urge you to do a search here on stackexchange. There are lots of resources here that will help you understand how to design with that particular type of output in mind.